# Can I eat smaller amounts of food every 30 minutes?

Tags: nutrition, diet

I usually take a long time to eat a whole meal, and it feels quite agonizing after a while.

Doctors usually recommend eating every 3 hours or so. I wonder if it's healthy if I eat a smaller amount of food every 30 minutes or so.

Consider that I calculate the amount of food of that "micro-meal" correctly, and fill those "micro-meals" with vegetables, fruits and all kinds of healthy stuff.

In that scenario, will I have health problems?

Comment: Doctors don't recommend eating every 3 hours. Eating every 30 min sounds impractical.  As for health there is no generally accepted theory on what the daily blood sugar levels should look like.